# How can I create an interface for API data in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios

So I'm getting data from TMDb API(movies) and my App.js looks like this:

```
const App = () => {

  const [movies, setMovies] = useState<MovieType[]>([]); //state for setting movies to api data

  useEffect(() =>{
    fetchMovies();
  }, [])

  async function fetchMovies() {   //function for fetching data
    try{
      let apikey = '{api_key}';
      let url: string = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?sort_by=popularity.desc&api_key=';
      url = url + apikey;
      const response = await axios.get<MovieResults[]>(url);
      setMovies(response.data.results);    //and here I get an error: Property 'results' does not exist on type 'MovieResults[]'
    }catch(e){
      alert(e);
      console.log(movies);
    }
}

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      <Hero movies={movies}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

My types and interfaces:

```
export type MovieType = {
        vote_average: string,
        title: string,
        tagline: string,
        date: string,
        img: File,
    };

export type MovieResults = {
    results: MovieType[],
};

export interface MovieProps {
     movies: MovieType[],
      };
```

As you can see, I have types and interfaces, I created MovieType for passing props, and MovieResults for getting results from API. But I have an error when I try to set movies to api data: `Property 'results' does not exist on type 'MovieResults[]'`
It's weird, because I actually have "results" property in MovieResults.

Comment: there is a `data` object before `results`. so interface should be `data:movieResults[]` you need to create one more interface for data and refer results from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you meant to do `axios.get<MovieResults>`. If you do `axios.get<MovieResults[]>`, it will expect an array of `MovieResults` which I think is not what you want.

If you use `MovieResults[]` as type, you are basically expecting the `data` to be the following

```js
[
  { results: ... }, 
  { results: ... }, 
  { results: ... }, 
  .
  .
  .
]
```

So, you are trying to read `results` from an array, which is not defined.

But, if you use `MovieResults` as type, the format of `data` will be the following

```js
{
  results: ...
}
```

Here, you are reading `results` from an object.

Comment: wow..you're right, that was actually the problem. but could i ask why? because i get an object from the api, so it shouldn't be `MovieResults[]`?

Comment: Updated the answer. Let me know if that clarifies.

Comment: so basically..results has a type of MovieType[], which is an array, so i guess that's why results is an object which contains arrays with movies? because when i console log results, it displays an array

Comment: Yea. The `MovieResults` is an object with `results` property. So, you don't need to add `[]` to it.